# length was null using Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

App is working smoothly. But Error is showing on the console.

> The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
>   length User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
>   StreamProvider>
>   file:///Users/Documents/flutter_job_manager/lib/components/router.dart:23:24

I use Firebase Cloud Storage with Provider

**Error is coming here:(on my generateRoute)**

```
  case AddCategory.route:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => StreamProvider<List<CategoryModel>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().streamCategories(),
          child:  AddCategory()
      )
    );
```

just to know: 
`streamCategories` in DatabaseService()

```
  Stream<List<CategoryModel>> streamCategories() {
    var ref = _db.collection('categories');

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => CategoryModel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }
```

`AddCategory` in StatelessWidget

```
      StreamProvider<List<CategoryModel>>.value(
          value: db.streamCategories(),
          child:ListView.builder(
                itemCount: category.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        category[index].categoryName,
                        ),
                  );
                }),
          ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `initialData`. Now no errors on console..

```
  return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => StreamProvider<List<CategoryModel>>.value(
        initialData: [CategoryModel(categoryName: "no current categories")],
        value: DatabaseService().streamCategories(),
          child:  AddCategory()
      )
    );
```